# get user_likes is working but only around 30 likes of each category and not all of them?

Tags: limit

First, thank you for your future help and sorry for my english...

I just went to create a new app, who take all user_likes and put them on the database, but my problem is that only around 30 likes are tooken on each category:

Is it a Facebook limit or I've to put something on my code ?

Thank you !

Comment: Code, please. There's not much to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry,

Login :

```
function P_FB_login() {
FB.login(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {

window.location = "<?php echo RACINE;?>?fb_connect";

} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

} else {

}
}, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_likes,user_friends,user_birthday,user_interests'});
}
```

And update :

```
if ($update) {

addhobs($facebook->api('/me/music'),$user->usersId);

addhobs($facebook->api('/me/games'),$user->usersId);

addhobs($facebook->api('/me/television'),$user->usersId);

addhobs($facebook->api('/me/books'),$user->usersId);

addhobs($facebook->api('/me/movies'),$user->usersId);

addhobs($facebook->api('/me/likes'),$user->usersId);

addhobs($facebook->api('/me/interests'),$user->usersId);


checkFriendFB($facebook->api('/me/friends'),$user->id_fb);
$test .= 'getAll ';
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever come to a resolution to this issue? I'm having the same issue as well!

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the Facebook API update log page:
Default Result Limit - All edges will now return 25 results per page by default when the limit param is not specified.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

You'll want to set the limit manually yourself.

Cheers